# SQL Server 2005 - Is there a way to lock a SELECT in a Transaction?

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to lock a SELECT in a Transaction? If a SELECT occurs, no more SELECTs are executed while the first one is not finished.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you wanting to do this?

Comment: "lock a SELECT in a Transaction"? Is it supposed to detect it's in a transaction, rather than otherwise? Or do you mean "execute selecs serially in a transaction - execute one completely before starting another"? Which is I think the only way it ever works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I understand your question correctly, but if you want to impose more rigorous locking than SQL Server's default, then you can either bump up the isolation level or use a locking hint. This can be useful if you first need to SELECT something and then later, based on the value SELECTed, do an UPDATE. To avoid a phantom UPDATE from another transaction (wherein the value you previously SELECTed was changed in b/w the SELECT and UPDATE), you can impose an update lock on your SELECT statement.

Eg:

```
 select * from mytable with (holdlock, xlock)
```

Notice that the SELECT statement above uses the more rigorous update lock & holds that lock for the duration of the transaction. You would also want to wrap your statements in an explicit transaction, as in:

```
begin transaction
select * from mytable with (holdlock, xlock) -- exclusive lock held for the entire transaction
-- more code here...
update mytable set col='whatever' where ...
commit transaction
```

Be wary, of course, for long-running transactions.

Comment: +1 but: The updlock does not really prevent other Selects to be executed. It prevents other updlocks, this means updates and selects with updlocks.

Comment: OK, try something like this instead:

select * from mytable with (holdlock, xlock)

That will definitely block SELECTs occurring in the context of other connections.

Answer (score 2):

Might want to look at [Isolation Level instead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx) of a hint

Answer (score 0):

You'll need an isolation level of `SERIALIZABLE`:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
```

The other `SELECT` queries will block until the transaction completes in this case. The default level is usually READ COMMITTED.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you're looking for a pessimistic locking strategy but without acctually locking your data. look into [Application locks](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/application-locks-or-mutexes-in-sql-server-2005) in sql server.

Answer (score 0):

Changing your isolation levels is generally your best choice.

But, if for whatever reason that's not an option for you - you could also do an exclusive table lock...

```
select * from MyTable with (tablockx)
```

That would prevent any other selects on the table until your transaction is finished.