# pessimistic locking in sql server 2008 using NHibernate

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate

SQL Server doesn't support the "SELECT FOR UPDATE" syntax, which is used by NHibernate for pessimistic locking.
I read [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804338/sql-server-2005-is-there-a-way-to-lock-a-select-in-a-transaction) descriptions of other alternatives (I liked the "SELECT WITH (...)" because it's quite close).

however NHibernate doesn't seem to support this syntax.

do you have a workaround for this?
I believe this can be achieved by tinkering with NHibernate internals, but that's not cost effective for me at the moment (learning curve).
I could also perhaps use a stored procedure with application locks, and access that from NHibernate.
any other suggestions?
(aside from always reading before writing...)

Comment: Isn't that pessimistic locking? Optimistic locking is when you *don't* lock upfront, hoping the row doesn't change, and you test for changes in the update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NHibernate has a version strategy for optimistic locking:

http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/15/nhibernate-mapping-concurrency.aspx

Comment: thanks, Ayende's blog is great and although I mistakenly asked about optimistic locking (although I need pessimistic lock), this post helped me - since it demonstrated how a session.Get<Person>(1,LockMode.Upgrade); translated to ... FROM ... WITH (updlock, rowlock) - which means NHibernate (at least 2.x) DOES support SQL Server's pessimistic locking syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I don;t know much about NHibernate, but in SQL columns of ROWVERSION type are commonly used to implement optimistic locking. Example [here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2008/11/27/defensive-database-programming-if-statement-vs-where-clause.aspx)